Measuring Robustness in Variational Bayesian Inference and Nonlinear Filtering
I am interested in how to properly pose/measure robustness, in a qualitative or potentially quantitative manner, when inferring a probability density function (pdf) either by Bayes' rule or a variational law. I am mainly curious how people would approach/formulate the problem in general, rather than a specific solution; although, solutions for a specific modeling inaccuracy are still interesting.
Problem Background: Suppose I have a random vector, the "state," $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, comprised of the parameters necessary to completely describe the state of a physical system, e.g., position and velocity. This vector evolves through time either stochastically, via an Ito differential equation, or deterministically, and observations, $\boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, are taken periodically throughout the trajectory. Assume the underlying dynamical process is Markovian.
At a given epoch (i.e., consider a single prior pdf, $p(\boldsymbol{x})$, and conditional measurement pdf, or likelihood, $p(\boldsymbol{z} | \boldsymbol{x})$, I wish to approximate the true Bayesian posterior, $p(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z} )$, using a variational principle,
\begin{equation}
  q^*(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z}) = \text{argmin}_{q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \ \mathscr{F}[q(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z}) ] \ ,
\end{equation}
where $q^*$ is the optimal variational approximation and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of all possible pdfs on $\mathbb{R}^n$, or, to avoid over formulation, at least those measures that are more-or-less nice and applicable to engineering applications. Given the models are defined accurately, a convenient variational formulation is
\begin{equation}
   \mathscr{F}[q] = -\mathbb{E}_q \{ \log p(\boldsymbol{z} | 
  \boldsymbol{x}) \} + D[ q || p(\boldsymbol{x}) ] \ ,
\end{equation}
where $D$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence, $\mathbb{E}_q$ is the expected value operator with respect to $q$, and $\mathscr{F}$, in this instance, aligns with the popular variational Bayesian inference optimization functional (note that I have not yet imposed a specific parametric form of $q^* $, e.g., a multivariate Gaussian or Gaussian mixture, etc.), where it can readily be shown that $q^* = p(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z})$.
However, we inevitably incur errors in the underlying statistical models, i.e., the likelihood function and prior state pdf. For certain model misspecifications, it may be more convenient to optimize a robust variational principle at the expense of estimation accuracy/precision under ideal conditions. For example, I have had success with mitigating slight likelihood discrepancies and outliers using a variational Gibbs inference approach,
\begin{equation}
  \mathscr{F}[q] = \mathbb{E}_q \{ \ell(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{z}) \} + D[q || p(\boldsymbol{x})] \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\ell$ is a loss function taking the place of the negative expected log-likelihood and leading to $q^* \propto e^{-\ell(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{z})} p(\boldsymbol{x})$; unfortunately, demonstrating robustness and selecting $\ell$ seems to be very ad hoc, where we maybe examine influence functions or run a Monte Carlo analysis to tune $\ell$ to a specific modeling discrepancy.
Problem Statement: To that end, I now want to pose a problem that has been on my mind for the last couple of days. Is there a more general way to examine and qualitatively describe robustness in this setting?
For instance, say there is some unknown collection of parameters, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$, that parameterize the true likelihood function, call it $p(\boldsymbol{z} | \boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{\eta})$, where when $\boldsymbol{\eta} = \boldsymbol{0}$, the true likelihood function aligns exactly with the model available to the estimator. For the sake of simplicity, I will constrain the problem to only misspecifications in the likelihood function; however, errors in approximating the dynamical system between measurements embed themselves as errors in the prior state pdf as well. We can then write the information loss in representing the true Bayesian posterior, now assumed a function of $\boldsymbol{\eta}$, by $q^* $ as
\begin{equation}
  D[q^*(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z}) || p(\boldsymbol{x} | 
  \boldsymbol{z} ; \boldsymbol{\eta} )] \ .
\end{equation}
Is there some bound or quantification of $D$ that can be achieved that demonstrates either (or both) insensitivity to small or large values of $\boldsymbol{\eta}$. For instance, Ref. 1 posits in Definition 1 a linear upper bound
\begin{equation}
  D[q^*(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z}) || p(\boldsymbol{x} | 
  \boldsymbol{z} ; \eta )] \leq K | \eta | \ ,
\end{equation}
$\eta$ being a scalar in this case and where $K$ is a constant. However, the notion of a linear upper bound seems unmotivated as a general measure of robustness; why not a constant upper bound? Or a quadratic one? The simplest, but perhaps least satisfying, answer is to examine each specific model misspecification of interest and compare the (hopefully) robust variational estimator with a naive ($\boldsymbol{\eta} = \boldsymbol{0}$) implementation of Bayes' rule, i.e., see which one yields the lower value of $D$ to the true posterior.
Huber, Ref. [2], uses a different approach, bounding the difference between the true generating pdf and one constructed from a series of $N$ independent, identically distributed data points (that may have contaminated samplings from a different distribution), in a manner analogous to Lyapunov stability, see Sec. 1.3 of Ref. [2], but, unfortunately, he has the luxury of considering the limit as $N \to \infty$, where the filtering problem only has access to one measurement at a time.
I do, however, like the idea of considering robustness as an analog of Lyapunov stability/control. Take, for instance, the system in the crudely drawn figure below, where $q^* $ represents the optimal variational posterior, assuming $\boldsymbol{\eta} = \boldsymbol{0}$, and, for analogy's sake, takes the form of an "equilibrium" solution. The true Bayesian posterior under nominal conditions, $p(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z} ; \boldsymbol{\eta} = \boldsymbol{0})$, then begets some initial "directed" distance, $D_0$, from the KL divergence (which is not a proper distance metric, but should provide ample metrization for this problem). This value, $D_0$, is the "cost of doing business," in that departing from Bayes' rule in favor a robust inference law is going to induce some $D_0 \geq 0$ when the models are described perfectly. As $|| \boldsymbol{\eta} ||$ increases, the value of $D$, $D_\eta$, changes as well. Is there a bound on how large $D_\eta$ can become that makes intuitive sense for defining robustness? The Lyapunov approach would ideally beget some limit for each $D_0 > 0$ as
\begin{equation}
  D_\eta = D[q^*(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z}) || p(\boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{z} ; \boldsymbol{\eta})] \leq \varepsilon \quad \forall \ \boldsymbol{\eta} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \forall \ || \boldsymbol{\eta} || \ .
\end{equation}
The prospect of bounded asymptotic stability, where $\lim_{|| \boldsymbol{\eta} || \to \infty} D_\eta \leq \textit{const.}$ seems hopelessly optimistic, as what information can truly be garnered from a system that is infinitely misspecified? Again analogous to Huber, Ref. [2], is there a "breakdown" point/region that can be logically defined that $D_\eta$ should remain in for $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ in some region $\mathcal{A}$? I am very interested in how others think about and pose the concept/quality of robustness in a Bayesian filtering setting.
$\boldsymbol{\eta}$" />
1 Calvet, Laurent E.; Czellar, Veronika; Ronchetti, Elvezio, Robust filtering, J. Am. Stat. Assoc. 110, No. 512, 1591-1606 (2015). ZBL1378.62091.
[2] Huber, Peter J., Robust statistics, Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics. New York etc.: John Wiley & Sons. IX, 308 p. (1981). ZBL0536.62025.
